# Active admin multiple file/image upload with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin, formtastic

I use Active admin and I need upload Galleries with a lot of images. How can I do it?
My code:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :images

  attr_accessible :name, :publish, :images, :image, :images_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true

end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery

  attr_accessible :url
  has_attached_file :url, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end


ActiveAdmin.register Gallery do
    form html: { multipart: true }  do |f|
          f.inputs  do
            f.input :name
            f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true}
          end            
          f.buttons
    end  
end
```

And I have this error:

```
Image(#70319146544460) expected, got ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile(#70319105893880)
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved the problem yet?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Gallery do
  form multipart: true do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name

      f.has_many :images do |p|
        p.input :url
      end
    end

    f.actions
  end
end
```

Comment: I get `undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass` for this. Seems to be the `has_many` at fault.

Comment: Actually, using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the model (pointed out by the OP) fixed it for me. My bad!

Comment: are we able to upload multiple files at one go using this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to solve it:

Try to do the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Gallery do
  form html: { multipart: true }  do |f|
    f.inputs  do
      f.input :name
      file_field_tag("gallery_images_url", multiple: true, name: "gallery[gallery_images_attributes][][url]")
    end            
    f.buttons
  end  
end
```

I got to that solution by following this blog post: http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/multiple-file-upload-with-rails-3-2-paperclip-html5-and-no-javascript